# How to create NACL rule dynamically for Gateway Endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to slove this mystery for a while but don't see I'm going anywhere, hence decided to ask here.
I'm creating AWS `Gateway endpoints` for *S3* and *dynamodb*, which returns a set of ip address each per VPC and then I'm trying to create the NACL rules to allow each IP address through it, as part of the same plan. With two variables like this:

```
> keys(var.vpc_list)
tolist([
  "main",
  "pub",
])
> var.vpc_endpoints_gw
tolist([
  "dynamodb",
  "s3",
])
```

I can easily do something like:

```
// Gateway Endpoints NACL rules
resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "gw_eps" {
  for_each = merge([
    for VPC in keys(var.vpc_list) : {
      for K, V in flatten([
        for EP in var.vpc_endpoints_gw : aws_vpc_endpoint.gw_eps["${VPC}:${EP}"].cidr_blocks
      ]) :
      "${VPC}:${V}:${K}" => {
        idx  = K,
        addr = V,
        vpc  = VPC
      }
    }
  ]...)

  cidr_block     = each.value.addr
  rule_number    = 200 + (2 * each.value.idx)
  ....
  ....
}
```

but it won't work when adding new VPC, as the ***The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply***, hence will fail.

I'm not in a sitution to do any targetd deployment and the entier IaC automation is broken due to this. What can I do here to get around this issue?

-S

Comment: The error message is related to config outside of the question. On a side note: would `zipmap` help at all here with that nested `for` expression?

Comment: @MattSchuchard not sure what you mean - the question is here because of that issue. If you forget about the error message (or whatever the error message is), the actual issue still doesn't change - as GW Endpoints assign the `cidr_blocks` dynamically and they are per VPC, when adding a new VPC, TF has no idea how many time it needs to itarate over the IPs returned by `aws_vpc_endpoint` resource.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, not sure about re. `zipmap` - it needs equal number of keys abd values to work and in my case it's not.